# How to Change Screen Resolution on Unity 8

Tags: screen, display-resolution, unity8, 4k-monitor

I am using the XPS 13 4k Version Laptop.
Unity8 itself looks very nice but is currently hardly usable for me due to scaling issues as everything is very tiny. 
I cannot find an option to change screen resolution or similar to fix this.

Any Ideas on how to procede? Perhaps the Grid Unit setting can be altered manually for the time being but I do not know how.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Go to System settings and displays. There change the scale factor

Comment: @George Which exactly means what? I couldn't find such an option either.